# android getAdapter().getCount() returning 0

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a spinner which is populated using a CursorLoader. It gets populated correctly. However spinner.getAdapter().getCount() keeps returning 0. why is that :(

My spinner class is

```
public class CategorySpinner extends Spinner implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  Context myContext;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

  public CategorySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    myContext=context;
  }


  public void fillData(int projectId) {

    String[] from = new String[] { Category.CATEGORYNAME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label1 };
    int layout = R.layout.category_list_item;
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("ID", projectId);

    EditExpenseActivity mActivity=(EditExpenseActivity)myContext;
    mActivity.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, bundle,this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(myContext, layout, null, from, to, 0);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.category_list_item);
    this.setAdapter(adapter);
  }


  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    String[] projection = { Category.FULL_ID,Category.CATEGORYNAME };
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyContentProvider.CATEGORY_LIST_PATH +args.getInt("ID"));
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(myContext, uri, projection,null, null, null);

    return cursorLoader;

   }

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
// data is not available anymore, delete reference
adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

}
```

The activity that is calling the spinner is EditExpenseActivity

```
public class EditExpenseActivity extends Activity {

private Context myContext;
private CategorySpinner sp_Category;
private Intent intent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_edit_expense);
    intent=getIntent();
    final int mProjectId=intent.getIntExtra("ID",0);
    myContext = this;
    sp_Category = (CategorySpinner) findViewById(R.id.input_category);
            //fill spinner with categories of the project with Id mProjectId  
    sp_Category.fillData(mProjectId);

    //so far so good .. spinner is populated perfectly

    int i=sp_Category.getAdapter().getCount();

    }
}
```

Debug shows i value to be 0. why???

Comment: Loaders load data *asynchronously*. By the time you call `getCount()`, the loader most likely hasn't finished loading yet. Try inspecting the value at some point after `onLoadFinished()` has been executed to see if it still returns `0`. If that's the case, make sure your query actually returns any results.

Comment: Thank you for sorting out this conceptual error. I did data.getCount() in the onLoadFinished() and it returned the correct value.